# Bayesian hierarchical beta regression: Jags error—dimension mismatch

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I’m trying to run a random coefficient Bayesian beta regression model as set-up in the code below. However, the code has been throwing errors about "dimension mismatch". I found that this error could be triggered by conflicting indexing or improper nesting, both of which I have tried to eliminate. My best guess is that I’ve not properly coded for random variable (bay and yr) models because the pooled version of the model worked. I’m hoping for some insights.

```
###Hierarchical model for random coefficient
n.bays = length(unique(mydata$bay.ind))
n.yr = length(unique(mydata$yr.ind))

data = list(
  jac = mydata$jac,
  lat = mydata$Latitude,
  p.vel = mydata$Prec_vel,
  bay = mydata$bay.ind,
  yr =  mydata$yr.ind,
  n.bays = n.bays,
  n.yr = n.yr)


inits = list(
  list(alpha = rep(0.09, n.bays), beta1 = rep(0.009, n.yr), beta2 = rep(0.005, n.yr), sigma = 0.05, mu.alpha = 0.02, mu.beta1 = 0.005, mu.beta2 = 0.007,sigma.beta1 = 0.02, sigma.beta2 = 0.02),

  list(alpha = rep(0.06, n.bays), beta1 = rep(0.005, n.yr), beta2 = rep(0.007, n.yr), sigma = 0.07, mu.alpha = 0.08, mu.beta1 = 0.006, mu.beta2 = 0.004,sigma.beta1 = 0.06, sigma.beta2 = 0.04),

  list(alpha = rep(0.04, n.bays), beta1 = rep(0.007, n.yr), beta2 = rep(0.008, n.yr), sigma = 0.04, mu.alpha = 0.06, mu.beta1 = 0.008, mu.beta2 = 0.009,sigma.beta1 = 0.09, sigma.beta2 = 0.07))


{
  sink("BetarandcoefJAGS.R")
  cat("
      model{

      # priors
      mu.alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
      sigma.alpha ~ dunif(0, 10)
      tau.alpha = 1/sigma.alpha^2
      mu.beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
      sigma.beta1 ~ dunif(0, 10)
      tau.beta1 = 1/sigma.beta1^2
      mu.beta2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
      sigma.beta2 ~ dunif(0, 10)
      tau.beta2 = 1/sigma.beta2^2
      sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)


      # likelihood
      for (i in 1:length(jac)) {
      mu[i] <- alpha[bay[i]] + beta1[yr[i]] * lat[i] + beta2[yr[i]] * p.vel[i]
      a[i] <- ((1 - mu[i]) / (sigma^2) - 1 / mu[i]) * mu[i]^2
      b[i] <- alpha * (1 / mu[i] - 1)
      jac[i] ~ dbeta(a[i], b[i]) T(0.001,0.99999)


      }


      # model for intercept by bay
      for (j in 1:n.bays) {
      alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mu.alpha, tau.alpha) 
      }


      # model for slope by yr
      for (j in 1:n.yr) {
      beta1[j] ~ dnorm(mu.beta1, tau.beta1) 
      beta2[j] ~ dnorm(mu.beta2, tau.beta2) 
      }



      }

      ",fill = TRUE)
  sink()
}


n.adapt = 3000
n.update = 5000
n.iter = 5000
jm.rancoef = jags.model(file="BetarandcoefJAGS.R", data = data, n.adapt = n.adapt, inits = inits, n.chains = length(inits))

update(jm.rancoef, n.iter = n.update)
zc.rancoef = coda.samples(jm.rancoef, variable.names = c("mu.alpha", "mu.beta", "sigma", "sigma.alpha", "sigma.beta"), n.iter = n.iter)
```

> Error:  RUNTIME ERROR: Cannot insert node into b[1]. Dimension
>   mismatch

Here's a link to a subset of my data:

https://fil.email/o2UNlS38

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try to save the 'yr' and 'bay' variables in your data list as factors. So, replace bay = mydata$Bay.ind with bay = as.factor(mydata$Bay.ind)

Comment: @P.R I tried your suggestion but the error persists

Comment: Update: I found the source of the error. In line 4 of the likelihood "alpha" should be replaced with a[i]

Comment: It looks like `alpha` is a vector, which is causing this issue when you are trying to input a scalar into `b[i]`